# HTML select tag with fixed headline?

Tags: html, css, select, scrollable, heading

I'm looking for a solution to make a scrollable select box with heading like in the picture. If I use a table, I can't choose any of the lines. I want the user to mark one option, so he can delete it when he hits the button. I'm looking for a simple html+css solution if it's possible.

If I use the select-tag I'm not sure how to add any headings.

Every suggestion is welcome!
[image: EXAMPLE]

What I've tried so far:

```css
div.tableContainer {
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid #963;
  height: 285px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 900px
}

div.tableContainer table {
  float: left;
}

thead.fixedHeader tr {
  position: relative;
}

thead.fixedHeader th {
  background: #C96;
  border-left: 1px solid #EB8;
  border-right: 1px solid #B74;
  border-top: 1px solid #EB8;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 4px 3px;
  text-align: left
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent {
  display: block;
  height: 262px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader {
  display: table;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%
}

tbody.scrollContent td,
tbody.scrollContent tr.normalRow td {
  background: #FFF;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
  padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}

tbody.scrollContent tr.alternateRow td {
  background: #EEE;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
  padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}
```

```html
<div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="scrollTable">
    <thead class="fixedHeader">
      <tr>
        <th width="20%">Header 1</th>
        <th width="30%">Header 2</th>
        <th width="50%">Header 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="scrollContent">
      <tr>
        <td width="20%">Cell Content 1</td>
        <td width="30%">Cell Content 2</td>
        <td width="48%">Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Cont asdkfh asoid hfoas ghdfoasgdojf gasdkjfgasd jfgaskjdfg kjasdgf kjasd gjkasgdfkj agskjdfgaskdjfgent 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Cont asdkfh asoid hfoas ghdfoasgdojf gasdkjfgasd jfgaskjdfg kjasdgf kjasd gjkasgdfkj agskjdfgaskdjfgent 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Cont asdkfh asoid hfoas ghdfoasgdojf gasdkjfgasd jfgaskjdfg kjasdgf kjasd gjkasgdfkj agskjdfgaskdjfgent 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Cont asdkfh asoid hfoas ghdfoasgdojf gasdkjfgasd jfgaskjdfg kjasdgf kjasd gjkasgdfkj agskjdfgaskdjfgent 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Cont asdkfh asoid hfoas ghdfoasgdojf gasdkjfgasd jfgaskjdfg kjasdgf kjasd gjkasgdfkj agskjdfgaskdjfgent 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Cont asdkfh asoid hfoas ghdfoasgdojf gasdkjfgasd jfgaskjdfg kjasdgf kjasd gjkasgdfkj agskjdfgaskdjfgent 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Cont asdkfh asoid hfoas ghdfoasgdojf gasdkjfgasd jfgaskjdfg kjasdgf kjasd gjkasgdfkj agskjdfgaskdjfgent 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1 Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Cont asdkfh asoid hfoas ghdfoasgdojf gasdkjfgasd jfgaskjdfg kjasdgf kjasd gjkasgdfkj agskjdfgaskdjfgent 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking for tips and I'm not asking for a code-example! I googled a lot, maybe with the wrong keywords. Your comment doesn't help at all if you don't suggest anything. Do you have any keywords? Am I on the right way with select-box and code a headline all around?

Comment: We don't do **tips**..we solve actual code problems. No, a `select` here is probably the wrong choice, you need to code a replacement that has similar but different functionanilty. Frankly, what you have here is essentially a scrolling `table`.

Comment: Ok, so this is the table I've tried.

Comment: A simple html+css solution for what you're trying to achieve does not exist, but an advanced one might.  At that point, you're better off just using JavaScript or rethinking your user experience altogether so it better suits native HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you learn to use DataTables which is well maintained & documented library which has a number of good plugins and a community of developer users.

```js
var myDTable;
$(document).ready(function() {
  //An example of JavaScript sourced data, though you can instead have your thead and tbody rows defined in your HTML directly
  var dataSet = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    dataSet.push({id:i, name:"Bob Dylan", email:"bob@columbia.com", phone:"512-973-2991"});
  }
  myDTable = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
      data: dataSet,
      columns: [
        { title: "Name", data:"name" },
        { title: "Email", data:"email"},
        { title: "Phone", data:"phone" }
      ],
      //select:true  Allows multiple row selection
      select:"single",
      pageLength:100,
      fixedHeader: true,
      dom:"frtip"
  });
  
  //Listening for event click
  $(document).on("click", "#myTable tbody tr", function() {
    //How to get the clicked row data
    var rowData = myDTable.row(this).data();
    console.log(rowData);
    
    //Get the selected row data
    var selectedRows = myDTable.rows({selected:true});
    var numSelectedRows = selectedRows.count();
    
    //Show hide delete button accordingly
    if(numSelectedRows == 0) {
      $('#deleteRowBtn').hide();
    } else {
      $('#deleteRowBtn').show();
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#deleteRowBtn", function() {
    var selectedRows = myDTable.rows({selected:true});
    var rowToDelete = selectedRows.data()[0];
    console.log("Delete this row: ");
    console.log(rowToDelete);
  });
});
```

```css
table.dataTable tbody>tr.selected, table.dataTable tbody>tr>.selected {
    background-color: #417fd8 !important;
    color: white !important;
}
table.dataTable.display tbody>tr.selected>.sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody>tr.selected>.sorting_1 {
    background-color: #2868c3 !important;
}
table.dataTable tbody>tr {
  cursor:pointer
}
table.dataTable thead th, table.dataTable thead td {
    padding: 2px 18px;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#deleteRowBtn {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  bottom: 10px;
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/css/select.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="display"></table>
<div id="deleteRowBtn" style="display:none">Delete Selected Row</div>
```

More resources:

https://datatables.net/

https://datatables.net/reference/option/select

https://datatables.net/reference/option/fixedHeader